# Java: Searching files using a char - scanner

Tags: java, file, search, char, user-input

I'm struggling to see why this isn't working.
It is meant to ask for the first letter of the name and return result based on matching char.
The txt file has many names set up like:

- Eddie Cochran 1938 - 1960
- Cliff burton 1938 - 1960
- Cliff burton 1938 - 1960
- James Dean 1938 - 1960 1968 - 1970 1978 - 1980

Currently it is just listing all names and dates. Could anyone give me some suggestions, Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class NameYear {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is the first letter? ");
    String input = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();
    char firstLetter = input.charAt(0);

    File file = new File("names.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);


    while(input.hasNext())
    {
       String firstName  = input.next(); 
       String surname  = input.next(); 
       String year = input.nextLine();  

        if(surname.charAt(0) == firstLetter);
         { 
           System.out.println(firstName + " " + surname + year);
         }
     }
 input.close();
}
}
```

Comment: You are calling input.close in your while loop.

Comment: Typo :|
code is working with input.close();  not in while loop.

Comment: @Aleksandar please turn your comment into an answer, @Nicholas, if the problem was the `close` please accept Aleksandar answer.

Comment: not*
Sorry another typo, bad day i guess.

Comment: Thanks aleksandar. It was a problem with the if statement.
I forgot to make surname lower case to match with the user input.

if (surname. toLowerCase(). charAt(0) == firstLetter) 

worked, thanks again.

Comment: @Nicholas make this as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is this line :

```
if(surname.charAt(0) == firstLetter);
```

Remove the semicolon at the end.

This is what your code looks like when you remove the brackets.

```
if(surname.charAt(0) == firstLetter);
System.out.println(firstName + " " + surname + year);
```

As you see these are just statements one after another.